# Does the 1-category construction of a topos of presheaves extend to the 2-Category of Groupoids?

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory, groupoids, 2-categories

In the case of 1-categories, we know there is a functor category 
$PSh(C):=[C^{op},Set]$, where $C$ is a small category,
and this functor category is a topos.  I am hoping this will extend to the case of 2-categories and especially the 2-category of groupoids.

Comment: Sorry, but what does "admits a topos of presheaves" mean?

Comment: Is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120698/is-the-2-category-of-groupoids-a-topos somehow related to this question???

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Hi, yes, I am still looking for a topos somehow related to the 2-category of groupoids.

Comment: Maybe you can try asking there.. Can you confirm what is “2-Category” of groupoids..

Comment: the category of 2-functors and natural transformations Gpd^op --> C, for C any 1-category is equivalent to the category Gpd^op/~ --> C of functors and natural transformations, where Gpd/~ has the same objects as Gpd but isomorphism classes of functors as arrows. The category [Gpd^op/~,Set] is a presheaf topos...

Comment: You've just edited the question to say "Normally this would mean" something that doesn't mention groupoids at all. Earlier, you wrote that the comment by @DavidRoberts "has been  suggested to help  with an answer." Either this comment **is** an answer, or you really need to clarify what the question is intended to be.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I would like this question to come to conclusion without being closed.  I believe, though I am not sure that David's comment is an answer.  What should I do?  When I said "normally", I am stating that I had an intuition from 1-cats, should I say this?  Is the question doomed?

Comment: I"m not objecting to "normally". I'm objecting to saying that "the 2-category of Groupoids comes with a topos of presheaves" means something that doesn't even mention groupoids or any 2-category. Whether David's comment is an answer depends entirely on what the question is, and that's not something I can guess. That's why I voted to close as unclear.

Comment: Give me a few hours and I will try to improve this

Comment: @DavidRoberts is Gpd the 2-cat of Groupoids in your comment?

Comment: @Ben what else could it be, given the universal property I state? Given a 2-category D and a 1-category C, the category of 2-functors and natural transformations 2Cat(D,C) and the category of 1-functors and natural transformations Cat(D/~,C) composition with D -> D/~ gives an equivalence Cat(D/~,C) -> 2Cat(D,C). (Here D/~ has as hom-sets the set of iso classes of the hom-categories of D)

Comment: It remains to be seen _why_ you want to do this, and what good you might do. Personally, I think any construction that passes to D/~, for D a 2-category, is the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gpd is the 2-category of groupoidd.

The category of 2-functors and natural transformations $Gpd^{op} \rightarrow C$, for $C$ any 1-category is equivalent to the category $Gpd'^{op} \rightarrow C$ of functors and natural transformations, where $Gpd'$ has the same objects as $Gpd$ but isomorphism classes of functors as arrows. The category $[Gpd'^{op},Set]$ is a presheaf topos.